# Looping through an array to display a quote

Tags: json, react-native

Attempting to loop through this array, stored in a JSON file. I want to be able to check if a quote is saved and then display it depending on whether it is saved or not.

```
 _toggleCheck() {
            var checked = !this.state.checked;
            this.setState({ checked: checked });
             // For loop to run through arrray and update booleans 
             for(int i = 0; i<quotesArray.length-1; i++;){    
                quotes.quotesArray[i].isSaved = checked;
             }
            this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(this.props.name, checked);

    }
```

In attempting to do this, I have come across this error and can not resolve it. Line 63 is the beginning of the for loop. I dont know how to use a for loop in react native and cant find any tutorials on line.

[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Maxwelll edited. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i<quotesArray.length-1; i++;){ 
                                          ^ remove this semicolon
```

By the way, are you sure you want `i < quotesArray.length - 1` instead of `i < quotesArray.length`? You're skipping the last element when you add `-1`.